# Is there any way to define state, non-bound to the componenttree - like svelte/store

Tags: state-management, qwik

I recently took a look into Qwik and liked most of what I saw.
Sadly, I didn't find any way to define state outside of a component. I also couldn't find any state management library that can work with Qwik (my only hope was nanostores).

So, am I not seeing something or is there no way to create state outside of components in Qwik?

In Svelte I would do such like this:

`store.ts`

```js
import { writable } from "svelte/store";
export const count = writable(0);
```

`App.svelte`

```html
<script lang="ts">
  import CountIndicator from './components/CountIndicator.svelte';
  import Counter from "./components/Counter.svelte";
</script>

<main>
  <Counter />
  <CountIndicator/>
</main>
```

`Counter.svelte`

```html
<script>
  import { count } from "../store";
</script>

<div class="counter">
  <button on:click={() => $count--}>-</button>
  <span>{$count}</span>
  <button on:click={() => $count++}>+</button>
</div>
```

I looked both in to the Qwik and Qwik City documentation. I also checked nanostores as they have support for even solid.js.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Context api just like React Context to define your state outside of your components.

https://qwik.builder.io/docs/components/context/

Comment: yeah thats what I went with. Thanks ^^

Answer (score 0):

Having a state non-bound to any component is currently **not supported** in Qwik:

> *[...] in Qwik the state must be part of the tree, for technical reason but globals are in general something to avoid even in other templates when doing SSR.*

Sources:

- https://github.com/BuilderIO/qwik/issues/645#issuecomment-1284273839
- https://hackmd.io/@qwik/data-principles#State-is-part-of-the-tree

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I now understand that a global store doesnt rly make sense on a SSR first Framework like Qwik.
A ServiceProvider ComponentWrapper will have to do I guess